# Is there any guides to assist a seasoned PHP developer wanting to learn c# and .net?

Tags: c#, .net, php

I remember when I switched from Classic ASP to PHP many years ago, and I came accross an awesome document on the net showing how the VBscript differed to PHP. It really helped me when I ported an old photo album software I made to PHP.

I was wondering if anyone knows a similar guide, from PHP to .net? If not, what are the best resources to start? Is there anything I need to *untrain* myself in doing, being a PHP developer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Learn ASP.NET: for PHP Developers**

This series of code casts and labs from Microsoft should really help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/dd861537.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Sucks they are in Word format though. I've got openoffice but it's still a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be into web development, I assume that you want to use .net and C# to make web projects. There are basically two flavors: ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC. Google for the latter, I think it will feel more "at home" concept-wise when you're coming from PHP.

Comment: I haven't seen much php-projects that use MVC or OO-principles.

Comment: @chrissie1 Modern, good ones do. There are a lot that don't however. But they get the job done. Check out Kohana for a framework that makes MVC easy.

Comment: Good PHP development is pretty often following a MVC (or similar) pattern. And in general, ASP.NET MVC is "closer to the metal", Web Forms abstract much more of HTML and CSS away.